# How do I submit a form in jQuery async?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

In mootools I would do something like `$('form_id').send({success:function(res){....}});`
What is the parallel syntax in jQuery?

Another words:
How would I put my form data (assume id='bob') into the following code

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$.ajax({   
   type: 'POST',   
   url: url,   
   data: $('#bob').serialize(),
   success: success,
   dataType: dataType 
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Wouldn't you know... It's right there in the documentation! :P

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Edit: okay okay...

```
$('#too_cool_form').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  //do some verification
  $.ajax({
    url: '',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data)
    {
      //callback methods go right here
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I really shouldn't be too lazy to check the document, but it's actually "jQuery.ajax( url [, settings ] )".

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing that ships with jQuery that will automatically AJAXify a normal form for you.

**Option 1** -- Intercept the form's [`submit`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event, scrape the data from form fields using [`serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/), and send using [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or [`post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), as suggested.

**Option 2** -- Use this great [forms plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/), which does all of option 1 for you.

Comment: Serialization is _not_ AJAXification. I disagree with your disagreement, @MatthewBlancarte

Comment: Perhaps we should start by defining AJAXification... I don't think we are on the same page. :)

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte AJAXification is my __Option 1__, and your answer. jQuery doesn't auto-enhance forms like mootools' `$('form_id').send()`.

Comment: Ah, okay. I see what you're saying. Just one more level of abstraction.

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte Cool. If you don't think this is wrong anymore, can I have my vote back? :)

Answer (score 0):

`$.post()` or `$.ajax()`

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

The documentation will explain it best: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/