# Form not getting posted

Tags: jquery, html

when i try to click on submit button my form doesn't post or reload on submission why so?

```
   <form class="form1">
     <input type="text" value="ABC"/>
     <input type="text" value="DEF"/>
     <select name="acces_specfi" class="selectpicker" data-size="10" data-style="btn-info">
                    <option value="public">public</option>
                    <option value="private">private</option>
                </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn-print"/>
```

--JS--

```
 jQuery('.btn-print').click(function(event){
                jQuery(".form1").find(':input').each(function(){
                    if(jQuery(this).val() && jQuery(this).attr('type') !== 'hidden'){

                        jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).replaceWith('<u>'+jQuery(this).val()+'</u>'));
                    }
                    else if(jQuery(this).val()===''){
                        jQuery(this).replaceWith('________');
                    }
                });
});
```

**---Update--**

this works

```
   jQuery(".form1").find(':input').each(function(){

                    if(jQuery(this).attr('type') !== 'hidden'){
                        jQuery(this).hide();

                        jQuery(this).after('<u>'+jQuery(this).val()+'</u>');
                    }

                });
```

but all select option are shown in form of list i don't know why i think because of i'm using bootsrap select [image: Bootstrap dropdown]

other then select normal text input works great

---Update-----

i replace it with normal select its working great i think because bootstrap select adds extra button and div thats what was causing issue

[image: text input]

Answer (score 1):

You can add `submit()` function to your form inside `click` event.

```
jQuery(".form1").submit();
```

**Note**: You should use it before you `replace` the `input` tags. If you need to use it after, you can keep the `input` fields and make them hidden.

---

If you don't want a *redirect* to happen you have to make an [async submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933830/how-do-i-submit-a-form-in-jquery-async).

```
$('.form1').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  //do some verification
  $.ajax({
    url: 'your/page/that/catch/the/request',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data)
    {
      //callback methods go right here
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: i don't think so this is the case because when i remove  jQuery(".form1").find(':input').each(function(){....}); my form get posted

Comment: i want to pass this in the form of string to php and i want to replace all my input with their value is it possible?

Comment: @MayuriS Yes, it is possible, you have to make a `POST` with `$.ajax` (this is done async). This way you send the post and update the page without redirecting.

Comment: no i don't care how my data goes through ajax or trivial http i just want  to replace input elements with their value and to get them in variable in form of string  and then i will just send it in ajax or through normal http post

Comment: @MayuriS I would like to understand better what you try to achieve, can you update your question?

Comment: 1upvote for "you can keep the input fields and make them hidden".

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are missing name attribute

```
 <input type="text" value="ABC"/>
 <input type="text" value="DEF"/>
```

these lines should be

```
 <input type="text" name="abc" value="ABC"/>
 <input type="text" name="def" value="DEF"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following:

```js
jQuery('.btn-print').click(function(event){
                jQuery(".form1").find(':input').each(function(){
                    if(jQuery(this).val() && jQuery(this).attr('type') !== 'hidden'){

                        jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).replaceWith('<u>'+jQuery(this).val()+'</u>'));
                    }
                    else if(jQuery(this).val()===''){
                        jQuery(this).replaceWith('________');
                    }
                });
    $('.form1').submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<form class="form1">
     <input type="text" value="ABC"/>
     <input type="text" value="DEF"/>
     <select name="acces_specfi" class="selectpicker" data-size="10" data-style="btn-info">
                    <option value="public">public</option>
                    <option value="private">private</option>
                </select>
    <input type="submit" class="btn-print" value='Submit'/>
</form>
```