# HTML form taking 15 seconds to submit using submit button if form contains large table

Tags: html, forms

I have a pretty standard form

```
<form name="mainContent" id="mainContent" action="/mySite/reporting/index.html" method="post">
```

I have a submit button in this form

```
<button type="submit" name="SubmitButton">Submit</button>
```

Normally if my form is pretty empty everything works as expected.
But sometimes my form contains a very large table (approx 100 rows and 75 columns), and I notice from the time I hit submit, to the time the request actually appears in chrome's network tab the browser completely freezes for about 15 seconds.

I tried putting an event listener on the button, and can see that the event listener is triggered immediately as soon as the button is pressed. If I use jquery to remove the table and then press submit, the browser submits the request immediately, so I assume this freezing is due to the browser doing something with this large table.

The weird thing is deleting the table using jquery.remove() takes less than a second. So I don't understand what html forms are doing that would freeze the browser for 15 seconds before resubmitting the forms

Comment: Hi, perhaps use the [profiler](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/rendering-tools/) to see what might be happening?

Comment: Does the table contain form fields?

Comment: IMHO I think this is what's happening -- Technically speaking when you hit **submit** .. You've *already* contacted the "next" page.  In this case:    `/mySite/reporting/index.html`  What's happening is `index.html` is crunching on those table elements and your browser is waiting for a response from `index.html`.. So it *seems* like your form is taking longer on the JS side .. But it's actually on the "processing" side.  You can view this by looking at the `network` tab in your developers options

Comment: @Zak, this is not the case. If i but an eventlistener on the submit for the form I can see the event is not triggered until 15 seconds have passed

Answer (score -2):

When you can get all expected data in front page such as html, jsp or php file, you can use ajax (jQuery) to send the data asynchronously.
Plz read the example: [How do I submit a form in jQuery async?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933830/how-do-i-submit-a-form-in-jquery-async)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with jQuery --  It's about forms and submitting.

Comment: I don't think it is your code's problem too. 1) You can check if some plugins interfere with your browser. 2) You can try if the problem exists also, when you use other browser, such as firefox. 3) The chrome will occupy the many memory in unkown reason. If you close it, the chrome will be working fine again. 4) try to delete the cookie.